# How does the second convolutional layer in tensorflow keras work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the fllowing model in keras.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(4, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, name='Conv2D_0', padding = 'same', use_bias=False, activation=None))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), name='Conv2D_1', padding='same', use_bias=False, activation=None))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

input_shape is (32, 32). So, for the first layer, if I have a an image of size (32, 32), I get 4 images of size (32, 32). So the input image is convoluted with 4 diffrent kernels. After the pooling layer, I get 4 images of size (16, 16).

The second convolutional layer gives me 8 images of size (16, 16). This layer has
4*8 kernels. The kernels have the size (3, 3, 4, 8). But I don't get, how the 8 output images are computed.

I thought for example for the first image I can do sth like:
H_i : i-th output image of the first Pooling layer
Ker_i : i-th kernel. (:, :, i, 0)

So the first output image of the second convolutional layer could be:
conv(H_0, ker_0) + conv(H_1, ker_1) + conv(H_2, ker_2) + conv(H_3, ker_3)

But this seems to be wrong.

Can anyone explaine me, how the second conv-layer computes the output images?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: the same way as in first layer. number of filters becomes number of channels in the output. take a look http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Comment: `This layer has 4*8 kernels.` - How do you define kernel?

Comment: I mean convolutional kernel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).

Comment: "the same way as in first layer. number of filters becomes number of channels in the output. take a look"

But this time I have 4 input images. How are the filters applied on these 4 images.

Comment: I found the answer. The filter kernels are flipped!